# Loading of base64 images in WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, base64

I've got a question related to the showing HTML data inside `WebView`.

I have quite big HTML string with some images with src in `base64` format. I'm reading this data from file. File reading is quite fast and I have no issues with this.

When it's only one image inside HTML - it works fine. But when at least a couple - it's lagging a lot. (It's loading about 30-35 seconds)

I tried to speed up it but no result.

This is the way I load HTML string.

```
 WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(hmtl), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

I use this function with base URL `"file:///"` because I'm going through the links(local) inside this file. So I guess it's obligatory to use this kind of function.

Can anyone help me with a solution?